# Weblogic 12c R2 (12.2.1.3) error myfaces timeout java.sun.com with web.xml 2.3 tag

Tags: jsf, weblogic, myfaces

I'm facing a very old project.

Trying to revive it on a WL server 12c as per title.

When I thought everything was set I got this stack:

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.myfaces.webapp.StartupServletContextListener).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
javax.faces.FacesException: java.net.ConnectException: Tried all: '1' addresses, but could not connect over HTTP to server: 'java.sun.com', port: '80'
 failed reasons:
  [0] address:'java.sun.com/156.151.59.19',port:'80' : java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: no further information

    at org.apache.myfaces.shared_impl.webapp.webxml.WebXmlParser.parse(WebXmlParser.java:115)
    at org.apache.myfaces.shared_impl.webapp.webxml.WebXml.init(WebXml.java:207)
    at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.StartupServletContextListener.initFaces(StartupServletContextListener.java:85)
    at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.StartupServletContextListener.contextInitialized(StartupServletContextListener.java:51)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager$FireContextListenerAction.run(EventsManager.java:705)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:326)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAsForUserCode(SecurityManager.java:197)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSecurityProvider.runAsForUserCode(WlsSecurityProvider.java:203)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:71)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager.executeContextListener(EventsManager.java:251)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager.notifyContextCreatedEvent(EventsManager.java:204)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager.notifyContextCreatedEvent(EventsManager.java:191)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.preloadResources(WebAppServletContext.java:1921)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.start(WebAppServletContext.java:3101)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.startContexts(WebAppModule.java:1843)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.start(WebAppModule.java:884)
    at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper$StartStateChange.next(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:360)
    at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper$StartStateChange.next(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:356)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:45)
    at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.start(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:138)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.start(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:124)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:233)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:228)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:45)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:78)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.StartModulesFlow.activate(StartModulesFlow.java:52)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$2.next(BaseDeployment.java:752)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:45)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.activate(BaseDeployment.java:262)
    at weblogic.application.internal.EarDeployment.activate(EarDeployment.java:66)
    at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.activate(DeploymentStateChecker.java:165)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.activate(AppContainerInvoker.java:90)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.activate(AbstractOperation.java:631)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.activateDeployment(ActivateOperation.java:171)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.doCommit(ActivateOperation.java:121)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.commit(AbstractOperation.java:348)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleDeploymentCommit(DeploymentManager.java:907)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.activateDeploymentList(DeploymentManager.java:1468)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleCommit(DeploymentManager.java:459)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentServiceDispatcher.commit(DeploymentServiceDispatcher.java:181)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.doCommitCallback(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:217)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.access$100(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:14)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer$2.run(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:69)
    at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:670)
    at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager._runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:352)
    at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager.runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:337)
    at weblogic.work.LivePartitionUtility.doRunWorkUnderContext(LivePartitionUtility.java:57)
    at weblogic.work.PartitionUtility.runWorkUnderContext(PartitionUtility.java:41)
    at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.runWorkUnderContext(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:644)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:415)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:355)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Tried all: '1' addresses, but could not connect over HTTP to server: 'java.sun.com', port: '80'
 failed reasons:
  [0] address:'java.sun.com/156.151.59.19',port:'80' : java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: no further information

    at weblogic.net.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:408)
    at weblogic.net.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:511)
    at weblogic.net.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:313)
    at weblogic.net.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:292)
    at weblogic.net.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:295)
    at weblogic.net.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:685)
    at weblogic.net.http.SOAPHttpURLConnection.getInputStream(SOAPHttpURLConnection.java:42)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.setupCurrentEntity(XMLEntityManager.java:647)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.startEntity(XMLEntityManager.java:1304)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.startDTDEntity(XMLEntityManager.java:1270)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDTDScannerImpl.setInputSource(XMLDTDScannerImpl.java:264)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$DTDDriver.dispatch(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:1161)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$DTDDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:1045)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:959)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:602)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:112)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:505)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:842)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:771)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:243)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:339)
    at weblogic.xml.jaxp.RegistryDocumentBuilder.parse(RegistryDocumentBuilder.java:162)
    at org.apache.myfaces.shared_impl.webapp.webxml.WebXmlParser.parse(WebXmlParser.java:99)
    ... 50 more
```

I'm quite sure that it's because of web.xml 2.3 DocType tag that says:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN" "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd">
```

I think it's a matter of definitions.
Tried lots of attempts but can't managed to get out of this trouble.

Comment: You have a prehistoric version of a lots of things. Your server does not contain the DTD that it wants to validate so it tries to retrieve that on the internet on prehistoric URLS that do not exist anymore. Hope you have more information now to work towards a solution.

Comment: yes I do know the situation, but I need a solution. I've just addedd ee6 javaee-api dependency and the problem seems bypassed since I'm facing other problems now.

Comment: Don't add java ee api's as a depedency in your application. It's a road to nowhere... https://www.google.com/search?q=weblogic+unable+to+resolve+dtd+web.xml

Comment: solved by using Weblogic 10.3.6 apparently...

Comment: Seriously, a downgrade from version 12 to version 10 is a solution? Waaaay better would be to make your web.xml a version 2.5...